# typescript window.devicePixelRatio

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use window.devicePixelRatio in a typescript file but this fails to compile with the message
"The property 'devicePixelRatio' does not exist on value of type 'Window'"

Is there a fix or must I just use the function outside of typescript?

Pete

Answer (score 4):

You can extend the `Window` interface with the feature you need - you can do this whenever something new(ish) hasn't made it into `lib.d.ts`. You may need to remove your extension later on when it does make it into `lib.d.ts` but the compiler will warn you at that time.

```
interface Window {
    devicePixelRatio: number;
}

var x = 1;

if (window.devicePixelRatio) {
    x = window.devicePixelRatio
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would go with Steve's solution if it works for you. Sometimes visual studio gets quirky and starts to complain variable already defined. Alternately you can always do:

```
var x = 1;
var win:any = window;

if (win.devicePixelRatio) {
    x = win.devicePixelRatio
}
```

or

```
var x = 1;

if ((<any>window).devicePixelRatio) {
    x = (<any>window).devicePixelRatio
}
```